# Passing parameters to a static method with PHP

Tags: php, static, parameters

I'm building my own framework, and I'm trying to pass a parameter to a static method. For some reason, the parameter is not getting passed. Here is the code:

Front.php:

```
if(URI::get(0) === "")
```

URI.php:

```
public static function get($index)
    {
        die($index);
        if(!filter_var($index, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            throw new Exception('You must supply an integer index for the URI segment');
        }

        return self::$uri[$index];
    }
```

At first I was getting an exception, so I added in the die statement to make sure the $index was actually getting passed correctly. Apparently it's not because when the script exits, nothing gets printed out for the index.

I am using php 5.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather odd, as it should work ; after testing this portion of code :

```
class ClassA {
    public static function a($param) {
        var_dump($param);
    }
}

ClassA::a(123);
```

I get this output :

```
int 123
```

Which indicates the static method did indeed receive the parameter (and I see no reason why it shouldn't, actually).

As a sidenote, you are ending with this portion of code :

```
die(0);
```

Quoting the manual page for [`exit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) *(which is the same as die)* *(emphasis mine)* :

```
void exit  ([ string $status  ] )
void exit ( int $status )
```

> If status is a string, this function
>   prints the status just before exiting.
>   
> If status is an integer, that
>   value will also be used as the exit
>   status. 
> [...] 
>  **Note: PHP
>   >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.**

You are using PHP 5.3, which is a more recent version than 4.2 ; and, in your case, **`$status` is an integer** -- which means it is perfectly normal to not have anything displayed, with the code your posted.

And, to finish : if you remove the `die`, your code ends up doing this :

```
if(!filter_var($index, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    throw new Exception('...');
}
```

With `$index = 0`

[`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/filter_var) returns the filtered value ; using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`, I suppose you are filtering to get an integer -- and 0 is integer.

Which means your call to `filter_var` will return `0`.

`0` is considered as `false` *(see [Converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting))* -- so, you will enter into the `if` block ; and the exception will be thrown.

Considering [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/filter_var) returns :

- The filtered data,
- or `false` when the filter failed,
- And that `0` is a valid data that can be returned,

You should probably use the `===` operator *(see [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))*, to compare the returned value to `false`. Which means some code that would look like this :

```
if(filter_var($index, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    throw new Exception('...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added an echo instead of a die, and the 0 is getting passed in...Unfortunately the exception is getting thrown which means that it doesn't think that 0 is an int.